# Magento 1.7:Show category image on category page in full width in a 2 column template

Tags: image, magento, categories

Can't find a solution for this issue running Magento 1.7. The category shown above in the main column. I want to show it above both columns, on page width. Here is an example: http://www.vimodos.nl/schoenen?art_sex=92

Anyone with a solution?
Your reply is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the reply. I followed your instructions and added a block called category.image  in the catalog.xml

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products"    template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
             <block type="catalog/category_image" name="category.image" template="catalog/category/image.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
```

After that I created a image.phtml file under  /template/catalog/category/

When reloading the category page it's empty, there is no error message. The widgets in the left side bar are visible.

Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a built in feature in Magento.

To enable it do the following:

- Log in to the admin panel
- Go to catalog->manage categories
- Select the category you want to add an image
- You will see a place where you can add an image (just upload it)
- Once you add an image it will automatically show in category page

**Update**

Here is the code to get the category image:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
$category->getImageUrl(); // remember to echo it out
```

In order to set this up above layered navigation, do the following steps:

- Add a block to the catalog.xml (in the: `<catalog_category_default translate="label">` section.
- Add the code above to the template file (that you referenced in the block above)

Let us know if you need further assistance with this

Comment: Still not able to create this. I have a working block above the category items. When I add your code between <?php  ?> in the .phtml nothing happends. Sure this is the right code?

Comment: What are you using as $catId ?

Comment: and change the block type from  ../category_image to catalog/category_view

Comment: @user1953441 please post the updated phml file code so that we can help you